# Opening a new console window with Java and having a Console object reference it

Tags: java

I'm trying to open a new console window in java and have a Console object referencing it. I know that the following code opens a console in windows,

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe");
p.waitFor();
```

Is there a way do `Console cons = ...` in conjunction with the above such that the console object is referencing the new one I just opened? Or am I completely going at this incorrectly and there is a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what the `Console` object in Java represents. From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html):

> Methods to access the character-based console device, if any,
>   associated with the current Java virtual machine.

It represents the console device associated with a JVM process, and its also not garaunteed to exist. If you want to interact with a system console launched from a Java process, then you will need to do so via its input and output streams.

Comment: Where did you pull the gray-boxed text from, could you post a link for future readers?  (This had me wondering for a moment myself!)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Is there a way I can get those streams though?

Comment: @CaptainMan - you get them from the process object - `p.getOutputStream()`, `p.getInputStream()`.

Comment: @Perception I meant the original source of the text.  I assumed it was quoted from some API documentation.

Comment: @BlackVegetable: **http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html**, first lines

Comment: @BlackVegetable - ah, I misunderstood what you were asking. I'll add the reference to my answer.